Name of actor from segment of Unsolved Mysteries
I am trying to identify an actor who portrayed "Glenn Wynn" in the "Best Friend's Sister" segment of Unsolved Mysteries with Dennis Farina, which appeared in S05E14. The segment also appeared in S05E18, with Robert Stack hosting, but the IMDb listing is incomplete.

The credits of this show often do not provide the names of all guest actors, so does anyone know who this is?

Have you looked on IMDb?

@Catija Yes, I have updated the question to indicate this.

This is just a guess, but he reminds me of Hill Harper - http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004991/

@AnneDaunted Me too. And Wikipedia seems to agree.

I think the others are right, it may be Hill Harper. He is mentioned in Unsolved Mysteries Wikepedia Page...


Wikipedia - Under: "Notable Actors"
In 1992, Unsolved Mysteries filmed in Texas and cast Matthew
  McConaughey to play a murder victim. This was one of McConaughey's
  earliest on-screen roles.[10] Cheryl Hines, Stephnie Weir, Bill
  Moseley, Ned Bellamy, Holmes Osborne, Scott Wilkinson, Daniel Dae Kim,
  and Brent Spiner also appeared on the series before receiving more
  notable work in Hollywood.[11] Comedian Blake Clark was interviewed in
  the "Comedy Store Ghosts" episode. Hill Harper also appeared in an
  episode about a woman looking for a childhood friend whom she later
  discovered was indeed her sister.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsolved_Mysteries
